# Does not receive data immediately by using readByte() in serial port

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I try to send command to a device and read data back via serial port, however it gives me a weird behavior.  I have to sendData() a couple of times(most twice) to get the data.  I do not want to use writeLine and I do not write a loop in my code (I have figured out already). My schema works like this. I set ReceivedByteThreshold to 1, so that each time the it receives the data from the device, the ReceivedData event handler is fired.  I read one byte at a time.  When it read CR, whose ascii is 13, I display the data on the label, but I have to send data (*idn?) more than once(sometimes can be done in one time but not consistent). See the pic for reference.  I am not sure why it happens.  Thank you in advance

```
Private Sub DataReceived(sender As Object, e As     IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    Dim ret As Integer
    ret = SerialPort.ReadByte()

    If ((ret <> 13) And (ret <> 10)) Then
        str &= System.Convert.ToChar(ret)
    End If

    If ret = 13 Then
        ret = SerialPort.ReadByte()
        If ret = 10 Then
            Me.Label2.Text = str
            str = ""
        End If

    End If


End Sub


Sub SendData(ByVal data As String)
    Try
        SerialPort.Write(data)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("fail to send data")
    End Try
End Sub
```

[image]

**[update]**

I changed my approach.  I just used a Do loop but the result is still not consistent. I chose not to use timer any more but just use ReceiveData Event Handler.

```
Private Sub DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    Dim ret As Integer
    Do
        ret = SerialPort.ReadByte()

        str &= System.Convert.ToChar(ret)
        If ret = 13 Then
            ret = SerialPort.ReadByte()

            If ret = 10 Then

                Exit Do
            End If

        End If

    Loop

    Me.Label2.Text = str
    str = ""

End Sub
```

I use Docklight to test my code, you can tell sometimes it sends twice in a row before get the data back.  I am not if it has race condition issue involved, thank.

[image]

Comment: Where is your send code?

Comment: I just added the send code.  Maybe it due of multithreading?

Comment: Is `str` a global variable?  The DataReceived event can fire with half of a response, so you need to read all the bytes and build a buffer with your strings and clear it after you see the <CR> (which is what it looks like you are doing).  I think there are several chars in the readbytes event and you need to check all the characters, not just `If ret = 13 Then`.  I think the times it works, you just got lucky.  You need to get all the chars from the bytes then check each char to see if its a <CR> and if it is, you know the response is done otherwise keep building your buffer.